# for loop not waiting for function to end

Tags: microsoft-metro, winjs

I have 5 links on a page and i have to check if all are links are working or not. Here is the code

```
 // iterate through each link and check if ti works.
 for(var i=0; i < 5; i++) {
    var ifLinkWorks = verifyLinkWorks(links[i]);
    if(ifLinkWorks){  OK  }
    else{ error }
 }
```

This is verifyLinkWorks function. It opens a link. After it get opened, it checks if the page is loaded properly

```
        function verifyLinkWorks(link) {
          return winjs.Promise(function(complete) {          
          link.click();  
          // wait for page to load
          return winjs.promise.timeout(4000).then(function () {
            // check if page is loaded
            var islinkOK = IsPageLoaded();
            complete(islinkOK); // i want verifyLinkWorks to return this value
            });
         });
    }
```

After reaching link.click(), it is not waiting for page to load. Instead it jumps to the if condtion in outer for loop (which makes linkWorks = undefined therefore,gives Error). How to make it wait in the verfifyLinkWorks function.
Thanks in advance...

Comment: what does `link.click()` do?

Comment: Link is a UI element. So, link.click() just clicks on that link and open the link's target page

Comment: Are you sure it isn't throwing an error?

Comment: Please post the if page loaded method

Comment: ifpageLoaded() { (document.getElementById("ID"))? return true: return false; }. Not exactly this, but functionality is same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to wait for the results of each promise, either all at once, or individually. As the actions are all async in nature, the code can't wait, but it can call a function when it completes all of the work.

Here, I've created an array which will hold each `Promise` instance. Once the loop has completed, the code waits for all to complete, and then using the array that is passed, checking the result at each index.

```js
// iterate through each link and check if it works.
var verifyPromises = [];
for(var i=0; i < 5; i++) {
   verifyPromises.push(verifyLinkWorks(links[i]));
}

WinJS.Promise.join(verifyPromise).done(function(results) {
    for(var i=0; i < 5; i++) {
        var ifLinkWorks = results[i];
        if (ifLinkWorks) {  /* OK */  }
        else { /* error */ }
    }
});
```

In case the `link.click()` call fails, I've wrapped it in a `try`/`catch` block:

```js
function verifyLinkWorks(link) {
     return WinJS.Promise(function(complete, error) {          
          try {
              link.click();  
          } catch (e) {
              complete(false);  // or call the error callback ...
          }
          // wait for page to load, just wait .. no need to return anything
          WinJS.Promise.timeout(4000).then(function () {
              // check if page is loaded
              var islinkOK = IsPageLoaded();
              // finally, call the outer promise callback, complete
              complete(islinkOK); 
          });
     });
}
```

If you want to check the validity of a URL, I'd suggest you consider using `WinJS.xhr` method to perform a `HEAD` request instead ([rfc](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html)). With each `link` variable, you can use a `timeout` to validate that there's a reasonable response at the URL, without downloading the full page (or switch to a `GET` and check the response body).

```js
WinJS.Promise.timeout(4000, 
    WinJS.xhr({
        type: 'HEAD',
        url: link
    }).then(function complete(result) {
        var headers = result.getAllResponseHeaders();

    }, function error(err) {
        if (err['name'] === 'Canceled') {

        }
        if (err.statusText) {

        }
    })
);
```

Comment: Wow, nice explanation. One problem which is still there is when i click on a link, it opens its target page. So, in the 2nd iteration, link becomes null, hence link.click() fails. Before executing link.click(), user must be on the main page(where all links are present). Where can i add something like goBack() (returns a promise), which takes it back from the target page to the main page.

Comment: I'd suggest you consider using WinJS.XHR to simulate downloading the page if possible rather than trying to get the browser to "click" a link. You could just use the `HEAD` verb. I added a bit of code for that idea.

Answer (score 0):

Ok heres the link to the msdn code sample for win js promise object.

[Promise winjs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211867.aspx)

now going through the code

```
<button id="start">StartAsync</button>
<div id="result" style="background-color: blue"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

WinJS.Application.onready = function (ev) {
    document.getElementById("start").addEventListener("click", onClicked, false);
};

function onClicked() {
    addAsync(3, 4).then(
        function complete(res) {
             document.getElementById("result").textContent = "Complete";
        },
         function error(res) {
             document.getElementById("result").textContent = "Error";
        },
         function progress(res) {
             document.getElementById("result").textContent = "Progress";
      })

 }
function addAsync(l, r) {
     return new WinJS.Promise(function (comp, err, prog) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            try {
                var sum = l + r;
                 var i;
                 for (i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
                     prog(i);
                }
                     comp(sum);
                }
                catch (e) {
                    err(e);
                }
            }, 1000);
        });
    }
</script>
```

you will see the **addAsync(3,4).then()** function. So all the code is to be kept inside that function in order to have a delayed response . Sorry m using a tab so cannot write it properly.

Also go through link [then for winjs promise](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229728.aspx)

Comment: Hey.thanks for the answer, but there should be some other way to do this.[This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15583972/for-loop-not-waiting-for-winjs-promise-completion) is doing the same thing, but it doesn't seems to work for me. Isn't there anything that can be done near 'wait for page to load' ?

Comment: Did you try putting ur code after the promise call inside then or done method these are the two provided. I guess you need to refactor your code. The iflinkworks parameter will be an argument for the promise.done() or promise.then() method and the code below will be inside {} of then or done method